# como subir proyecto de angular con laravel a un hosting?

Tags: laravel, angular

Realice un proyecto de angular usando las api_rest de Laravel obteniendo la información y ahora debo subirlo a un hosting, alguna idea?

Comment: Nunca trabaje con angular, pero si con react y vue, y dichos archivos solo son .js y lo ubico en la path_public, y funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Si, debes hacer el *deploy* de tu aplicación. En angular sería `ng build` y en laravel sería `php artisan build`. Luego debes asegurarte que los compilados estén en su sitio en el servidor. Todo dependerá de la configuración que tengas. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**Deploy de Angular v10**
1.- configurar las variables para que apunten a la dirección del servidor (API LARAVEL), el archivo lo encuentras en la ruta src/environments/environment.prod.ts
Ejemplo:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url: 'http://tudominiooip.com/api/'
};
```

2.- Ejecutar el comando **ng build --prod** este comando genera una carpeta **dist** donde encontraras todo el proyecto fronted compilado y listo para subir al servidor.

3.- Subir todo el contenido de la carpeta dist al servidor donde este apuntando tu DNS y también debes subir el .httaccess que te lo dejo a continuación:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    # --

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Ahora ya deberías ser capaz de ver tu proyecto publicado o al menos el frontend ;-)

Deploy Laravel V8
1 .- Debes configurar el archivo **config/app.php** como ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
'name' => 'PROJECTNAME-ABC'
'env' => 'production',
'debug' => false
'key' => 'pegaaquitucodigogenerado' /* Genera un código con el comando php artisan key:generate*/
```

2.- Configura la base de datos en el archivo **config/database.php**

```
'default' => 'mysql' /*o cualquiera disponible*/
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => '127.0.0.1',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'basededatosname',
            'username' => 'tuusuario',
            'password' => 'tupass',
            'unix_socket' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => [],
        ],
```

Bien como puedes ver son las opciones más básicas de configuración pero como regla general y para que tengas una idea se debe eliminar el archivo **.env** y pasar toda esa configuración a los archivos **.php** dentro de config, digamos si tu app envía correos electrónico las credenciales para el envío la debes realizar en la ruta **config/mail.php** y así con todo lo que necesites.

3.- Si publicas en un host compartido (con CPANEL) yo recomiendo que pases la carpeta **vendor** comprimida ya que no podrás utilizar de manera cómoda la consola, pero si tienes un VPN puedes subir todo tu proyecto excepto la carpeta vendor y una vez ahí instalar lo necesario para ejecutar el comando **composer install** que baja las librerías necesarias para tener nuestro **vendor**

Importante: Recuerda que tu DNS o sub-dominio debe apuntar a la carpeta **/public** dentro de tu proyecto Laravel

Ahora solo tienes que subir un respaldo de la base de datos o correr las migraciones de Laravel y Listo si navegas a la ruta raíz del dominio o subdominio donde subiste el proyecto laravel veras que se ejecuta sin problema.

Eso es todo espero te ayude...